# Can I extensively use JWT as the main media to store session data to prevent redundant database queries?

Tags: rest, session, jwt, stateless

A simple search on the subject returns a lot of articles/blog-posts and forum discussions on the caveats of the usage of JWT as a session storage media.

But I still see JWTs as a great session storage media. Because creating JWTs are not IO operations but querying databases (even the most lightweight memory based ones like Redis) are network/disk IO operations. So when scaling, having no IO for something instead of having it makes a lot of difference.

Here is my point of view. From many years ago we had issues managing server-side session storage and found that it doesn't scale, so we found that stateless APIs does not require storing session data on server and started using them. Then we found that we have issues calling the database to check user authenticity on every API call and found that giving the data to the user and signing it to prevent fraudulent claims is the way.

But why just user authentication? why not everything else! like when a user is carrying the id of some entities across APIs, we could transport the main objects using JWTs from clients, instead of the ids and redundant querying.

I know there are issues with invalidating data that we give to user, but it has its own solutions like using expiry times, redis blacklists, etc...

I also know that by doing it we are moving the BW usage from inside of our server (between the backend and DB) to the internet (between the user and server), but I find it more cost-efficient in most cases. Am I wrong?

**TLDR;**

Stateless APIs forces us to do redundant querying, not just for user data. Aside from authentication and user data, why we should not use JWT to store many other things to prevent this redundancy?

Answer (score 0):

What would be "everything else"? And how often would it change? Note that you would have to create a new signed JWT after every change, pass it to the client, make it forget the old JWT it used before and use the new one instead. That would be "session data". It would not be a proper use for JWT.

Comment: Creating JWTs are not IO operations but querying databases (even the most lightweight memory based ones like Redis) are IO operations. So when scaling having no IO for something instead of having it makes a lot of difference. The actual question is why really JWTs are not good for session data.